# Re-Casting a Property in Subclasses

Tags: objective-c, ios, subclassing

I have a set up where I have a hierarchy of view types with an equivalent hierarchy of model types. The set up is as follows:

The node model / data:

```
@interface GenericNode : NSObject
//blah blah blah
@end
@interface ShapeNode : GenericNode
//more blah
@end
```

the nodeViews, which will always receive an equivalently typed node as its model:

```
@interface GenericNodeView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) GenericNode * model;
@end
@interface ShapeNodeView : GenericNodeView
@end
```

However, the problem here is that the type of the `model` is always retained as the abstract superclass, forcing me to cast it every single time I want to access methods of properties of the subclasses.

Is there a way to recast class properties such that `exampleShapeNodeView.model` always returns an instance of `ShapeNode` and so on?

I have tried custom accessor methods such as

```
@interface GenericNodeView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) GenericNode * model;
-(GenericNode *)myModel;
@end
@interface ShapeNodeView : GenericNodeView
-(ShapeNode *)myModel;
@end

//in genericNodeView implementation
-(GenericNode *)myModel{
  return (GenericNode *) self.model;
}

//in shapeNodeView implementation
-(ShapeNode *)myModel{
  return (ShapeNode *) self.model;
}
```

but calling `[exampleShapeNodeView myModel]` still returns a `GenericNode`;

Comment: To be clear, it shouldn't *return* a GenericNode... it *returns* what is assigned to it. It's just that the compiler *thinks* it is a GenericNode, and so will complain if you call sub-class methods on it.

Comment: It is called a covariant return type, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842868/virtual-methods-return-type-in-objective-c

Comment: @ctrahey, you are correct, that is what I meant to imply. Messed up my keywords :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested this out, and it worked great for me:

In the child class, redeclare with the @property:

```
@interface GenericNodeView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) GenericNode * model;
@end
@interface ShapeNodeView : GenericNodeView
@property (nonatomic, strong) ShapeNode * model;
@end
```

You need to re-@synthesize as well, but there were no complaints by my Xcode (4.3.3)

Comment: This seems to work best. Also @dynamic can be useful here to still inherit the accessors

Comment: Cool hint, @frasmage. I encourage the use of `@dynamic` so you don't accidentally use a different ivar name. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are new to SO, I'll remind that marking an accepted answer is a win for you, the answerer, and the community. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make another variable and do `ShapeNode *anotherVariable = (ShapeNode *) someVariable`

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't "wrong" with all that casts, it just "feels" wrong to you. While there may be a code way to do what you want to do without Xcode complaining, you might consider changing the design a bit.

Of course, one way to go is to just make everything id type and then you can call whatever methods on the objects you want, but I'm guessing you don't want to do that.

Also, since you want to arrange the views in a view hierarchy I'm guessing that you want to reuse logic between them, i.e., classic object subclassing.

You might consider just putting the getter and setters on the 'leaf' classes, e.g., the classes in the hierarchy that don't have any children. This way you can make the signature as specific as you want and not need to cast things around, and since they aren't in the upper level classes you won't run into name clashes. I'll bet that the logic you want to leave in the parent classes is common in the sense that it's providing generic functions for the view, rather than logic that acts on the model.

Comment: I am aware that it is in no way "wrong" to simply cast each time I wanted to access the model, but in full implementation of the app that made for an absurd amount of casting. I just figured there must be a more elegant/logical OOP solution.

Comment: From a purely OOP perspective, there are a couple of ways to look at it. One is that a specific subclass of the UIView hierarchy that you made that has a specific model type just simply needs to take that type as a parameter. This means that your base class doesn't have a generic setter/getter.

From the perspective of other code that might be calling the getter on your UIView subclass, you can leave it up to *them* to cast the UIView subclass in order to "see" the proper/specific getter for that particular model. This effectively moves the casting to outside of your class hierarchy.